# Rollback the inner transaction of nested transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

suppose I have following sql statement in sql server 2008:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION    
SqlStatement1    
EXEC sp1    
SqlStatement3
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The code of sp1

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SqlStatement2
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

My question is: Is `SqlStatement3` actually executed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [transaction savepoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx). sp1 can use a pattern like the one described in [Error Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```

Such a pattern allow for the work done in sp1 to rollback, but keep the encompassing transaction active.

Comment: Problem here is, that the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION USP... does not reduce @@TranCount. You have to call commit after the rollback. Else you have no chance to commit the outer transaction if you want to (if the error of the inner transaction does not affect other changes)

Answer (score 37):

SQL Server doesn't really support nested transactions.  There is only one transaction at a time.

This one transaction has a basic nested transaction counter, `@@TRANCOUNT`.  Each consecutive `begin transaction` increments the counter by one, each `commit transaction` reduces it by one.  Only the `commit` that reduces the counter to 0 really commits the one transaction.

A `rollback transaction` undoes the one transaction and clears `@@TRANCOUNT`.

In your case, the funny result is that SqlStatement3 is run **outside** a transaction!  Your final `commit` will throw an "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION" exception, but the effects of SqlStatement3 are permanent.

For example:

```
create table #t (col1 int)
insert #t (col1) values (1)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update #t set col1 = 2 -- This gets rolled back
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update #t set col1 = 3 -- This gets rolled back too
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
update #t set col1 = 4 -- This is run OUTSIDE a transaction!
COMMIT TRANSACTION -- Throws error
select col1 from #t
```

Prints `4`.  Really. :)

Comment: This answer has the right idea, but the example doesn't prove anything because table variables aren't affected by rollback. If you remove the last UPDATE statement, the row's final value will be 3, not 1. Changing the table variable to a temp table would make the example valid.

Comment: @Endemic: Thanks, you're right! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Nested transactions can be used. To only rollback the inner transaction, use a savepoint and rollback to the savepoint. In case the inner transaction does not whether it is nested or not, `IF` statements can be used to find out whether to set a savepoint and whether to rollback or to rollback to a savepoint:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @WILL_BE_NESTED_TRANSACTION BIT = CASE WHEN (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    IF @WILL_BE_NESTED_TRANSACTION = 1
        SAVE TRAN tran_save
    BEGIN TRAN
        -- do stuff

    IF @WILL_BE_NESTED_TRANSACTION = 1
        ROLLBACK TRAN tran_save
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK

ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 6):

> Committing inner transactions is ignored by the SQL Server Database Engine. The transaction is either committed or rolled back based on the action taken at the end of the outermost transaction. If the outer transaction is committed, the inner nested transactions are also committed. If the outer transaction is rolled back, then all inner transactions are also rolled back, regardless of whether or not the inner transactions were individually committed.

[Nesting Transactions in Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

`Rollback transaction` on its own rolls back all transactions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299(v=sql.100).aspx

The statement will still be executed - try this

```
create table #t (i int)
insert #t values (1)  -- t contains (1)

begin tran
    update #t set i = i +1
    select * from #t  -- t contains (2)
    begin tran
        update #t set i = i +1 
        select * from #t -- t contains (3)
    rollback tran  -- transaction is rolled back

select * from #t -- t contains (1)
update #t set i = i +1
select * from #t -- t contains (2)
commit    -- error occurs
select * from #t -- t contains (2)
drop table #t
```

Comment: No, the answer is yes. The statement gets executed, but the commit will throw an error.

Comment: So, I can conclude that I can't put `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` inside a stored procedure that may be called from other statement.

Comment: You should check `@@trancount` and name your transactions

Comment: A funny result occur if I name my transaction: error occurs in inner rollback.. :D So it seem I must ceck @@trancount