# Multiple stored proc call in .Net under 1 transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

I have a .net web page in which two stored procs are called.
Both of these have begin-commit transaction in sql server.Also I am calling the second proc multiple times depending on some if conditions.

I want to wrap this whole process under a single transaction. I have looked around and found Sqltransaction and TransactionScope clases in C# will help me in this situation.

But I have never used them, always use transaction in sql server, and so do not know if the transactions in .Net will have problems as both my stored procs have their own Begin-commit transaction in Sql Server.

If they do conflict is there a way to get them to work under a single transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to call (e.g. existing or legacy) Stored Procs from .Net which use manual `BEGIN TRAN`, `COMMIT TRAN` / `ROLLBACKs` under a .Net `TransactionScope`, or if you manage the transaction from a `SqlTransaction`. (Although to state the obvious, if you can avoid using multiple transaction technologies, do so).

For the 'happy case' scenario, what will happen is that the `@@TRANCOUNT` will be increased when the `SPROC` transactions are called (just as per nested transactions in SqlServer). Transactions are only committed when `@@TRANCOUNT` hits zero after the outermost commit on the connection. i.e. `inner commits` will simply decrease `@@TRANCOUNT`. Note however that the same is not true for `ROLLBACKS` - unless you are using [SAVEPOINTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458678/314291), any rollback will rollback the entire transaction. You'll need to be very careful of matching up `@@TRANCOUNTs`.

You sound a bit undecided about `TransactionScope` vs `SqlTransaction`. `TransactionScope` is more versatile, in that it can span both single phase and distributed transactions (using `DTC`). However, if you only need to coordinate the transaction on a single connection, same database, then `SqlTransaction` would also be fine.

Comment: So the .net transaction will be the outer transaction and only it has to be managed in the web page code, right.No need to keep track of @@transaction counts? Sorry if my questions are silly but I still dnt understand c# transactions completely.

Comment: Yes, you have no need to worry about @@TRANCOUNT - this is just the way that SqlServer internally tracks the number of BEGIN TRANs (whether directly called by the proc, or indirectly via SqlTransaction or TransactionScope).

Comment: So,in essence C# transaction work in the same way as SQL transactions?