# Multiple ExecuteNonQuery on stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I want to execute the same stored procedure with different arguments using same connection and same transaction.
Ideally if any call to `ExecuteNonQuery()` fails, then the complete transaction should be rolled back.

Stored Procedure : Sample1

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sample1]
@start_date datetime, @end_date datetime, @empID int
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
   -- set of insert, delete and update
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
Declare @ErrorMessage Varchar(100), @ErrorNumber Int 

   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,@ErrorNumber,1);

END CATCH;

END
```

My C# Code

```
public int ExecuteSP()
{ 
   var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["__WaveDatabaseConnection"];
          int rowsAffected = 0;
          using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
          {
            connection.Open();
            var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {

          var command = new SqlCommand(_StoreProcedureName, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          command.Connection = connection;
          command.Transaction = transaction;
          command.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = site.ID;
          command.Parameters.Add("@start_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime();
          command.Parameters.Add("@end_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime();

          for (i = 0; i < 10; i++))
          {
            command.Parameters["@start_date"].Value = new DateTime().Add(i);
            command.Parameters["@end_date"].Value = new DateTime().Add(i+1);
            rowsAffected += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
          transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlException)
        {
          var sqlExceptionMessage = string.Format("Error number : {0}, Error Type : {1} Error message : {2}",
            sqlException.ErrorCode, sqlException.GetType(), sqlException.Message);

          try
          {
            transaction.Rollback();
          }
          catch (Exception exception)
          {
            sqlExceptionMessage =
              string.Format("ExecuteError : {0}, RollBack exception Error Type : {1} Error message : {2}",
                sqlExceptionMessage, exception.GetType(), exception.Message);
          }
          throw new Exception(sqlExceptionMessage);
        }
      }
      return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting this exception

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0

When I remove all the `BEGIN TRANS/COMMIT/ROLLBACK` statements from Stored procedure the first `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` is executed without any issue.
When it's called the second time it's throwing this exception:

> Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

I even tried using `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in SP. But it's not helping.

Kindly help me on how to commit all or rollback at the C# code and how to solve the above mentioned issue.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing - SQL server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265629/transaction-count-after-execute-indicates-that-a-commit-or-rollback-transaction)

Comment: @GSerg But when I remove all the transactions at SP, then getting different errors. Ideally I want to control the transactions at c# level only. Can you help me with the code on how to achieve it?

Comment: take a look at this post about SQL Server Myths - myth nested transactions are real http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: It is wrong to have stored procedures that execute multiple statements without a transaction. It is also wrong to have C# code that calls multiple SPs without starting a transaction. And because there are actually no true nested transactions, as Steve Ford noticed, you cannot balance your code by matching your begin trans with an equal number of rollbacks. Instead you should use a pattern, e.g. where you only roll back a transaction if you started it on the current level. You should e.g. detect from your SP that an ambient transaction exists, and if so, do not rollback.

Comment: Take a look at this blog which explains when a SQL Server error of level 16 will cause these symptoms. You need to check the XACT_STATE to determine if the transaction is commitable or not. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx

Comment: It is bit confusing for me, can point out the exact error and the correction needed in my code ? So that I can understand in a better way.

Comment: It is difficult to point out the exact error because there isn't one. The entire code should have been written differently, with "nested" transactions in mind.