# Why can't I call Procedure with Transaction inside another Procedure with Transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a proc which calls another proc name b:

```
Create PROC a
AS
    BEGIN   
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            IF ( 1 = 1 )
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(50);
                    EXEC dbo.b @ReturnMessage = @ReturnMessage OUTPUT; -- varchar(50)

                    IF ( @ReturnMessage = 'aaaa' )
                    begin
                        PRINT 'anuj';
                        end
                END;
            COMMIT   TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
        END CATCH;
    END;
```

The b proc is :

```
Create PROC b
    (
      @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            IF ( 1 = 1 )
                BEGIN

                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                    SET @ReturnMessage = 'aaaa';
                 RETURN;
                END;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;
        END CATCH;

    END;
```

When I execute Exec dbo.a

I get the following message:

```
Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Procedure a, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 0]
The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure b, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

Can anyone say what I have done wrong? This is just an example that I want to implement . Is there better way to handle such transactions

UPDATE: OK I did the following changes to my proc b , I used transaction savepoint and Trancount and its working now:

```
ALTER PROC b
    (
      @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @trancount INT;
            SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT;
            IF @trancount = 0
                BEGIN
                    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                END;
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SAVE TRANSACTION b;

                    IF ( 1 = 1 )
                        BEGIN

                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION b;
                            SET @ReturnMessage = 'aaaa';
                            RETURN;
                        END;

                END;

            IF ( @trancount = 0 )
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @trancount = 0
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END;
            ELSE
                IF @trancount > 0
                    BEGIN
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION b;
                    END;
            THROW;
        END CATCH;

    END;
```

Comment: You know that `rollback` rolls back everything, not just the most recently started transaction, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265629/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12456579/11683.

Comment: You *can*. If you mix up commits with rollbacks though, you'll easily end up with unmatched rollbacks or orphaned transactions

Comment: Add some print-statements to follow the flow. Also use @@TRANCOUNT before rollback/commit

Answer (score 0):

Handle transactions in the procedure that started the transaction with throw... Use @@TRANCOUNT.

```
alter PROC a
 AS
     declare @ret int;

    BEGIN   
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        IF ( 1 = 1 )
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(50);
                EXEC @ret = dbo.b @ReturnMessage = @ReturnMessage OUTPUT; -- varchar(50)
                if @ret <> 0
                begin
                    ;throw 50000, 'ErrorA', 1;
                end

                IF ( @ReturnMessage = 'aaaa' )
                begin
                    PRINT 'anuj';
                    end
            END;
        COMMIT   TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
END;

alter PROC b
(
  @ReturnMessage VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        IF ( 1 = 1 )
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnMessage = 'aaaa';
                throw 50000, 'ErrorB', 1;
                RETURN 1;
            END;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        if @@trancount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;

END;
```

Comment: That formally guards from the mismatch count error, but is wrong in principle. You should not be rolling back transactions that you did not start. It makes writing correct code very difficult if that code wants to call your code.

Answer (score 0):

The rollback will rollback all transactions.

Maybe you could use save points.

As I commented, you could use @@TRANCOUNT before rollback/commit just to get rid of the error, or 'merge' them, not to nest transactions independently.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82681/how-to-rollback-when-3-stored-procedures-are-started-from-one-stored-procedure/82697

[Rollback the inner transaction of nested transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456579/rollback-the-inner-transaction-of-nested-transaction)